# std::deque - subscript out of range

Tags: c++, std, deque

I am writing a plugin for SA-MP, based on AMX and have occured an annoying problem. I am using a deque and a function to find & delete an element. (like this one below)

```
enum PARAM_TYPE {
    PARAM_TYPE_CELL,
    PARAM_TYPE_ARRAY,
    PARAM_TYPE_STRING,
};

struct params_s {
    enum PARAM_TYPE type;
    struct params_s * next;
    cell free;
    cell numData;
    cell arrayData[0];
};

struct timer_s {
    AMX * amx;
    int id, func, interval, repeat;
    long long unsigned int trigger;
    struct params_s * params;
};

std::deque<struct timer_s *> gTimers;

void DestroyTimer(struct timer_s * t) {
    for (int i = 0; i != gTimers.size(); ++i) {
        if (t == gTimers[i]) {
            gTimers.erase(gTimers.begin() + i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I call DestroyTimer() I get this error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression: deque subscript out of range
```

I can add elements, read and modify them, but I can't delete them.

Thank you.

Comment: What you are doing seems utterly complicated for something so simple. What is wrong with `std::find` + `deque::erase` or even better the Erase-Remove Idiom? Also, are you sure you don't need to call `delete`?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [erase remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom):

```
void DestroyTimer(struct timer_s * t)
{
  gTimers.erase(remove(gTimers.begin(), gTimers.end(), t), gTimers.end()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the actual error, the idiomatic way would be:

```
gTimers.erase(std::remove(gTimers.begin(), gTimers.end(), t), 
              gTimers.end());
```

This will be safer and faster than what you are doing now (catches
duplicates, no need to reallocate).

This is called  [Erase-Remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

For the actual debug assertion: Debugging iterators are a standard
extension and maybe broken in some cases.

NB: You want to call `delete` on the timer, if it is owned by the deque, to prevent leaking memory.

Comment: Yeah, actually I'm calling delete on that timer and it's parameters, however, I removed that piece of code as it was irrelative to my error.